# Element need to split into two elements in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have element

```
<PredecessorActivityUID>000005001302-0030</PredecessorActivityUID>`
```

in XSLT 2.0 I need to split it into two elements as

```
<PredecessorActivityUID1>000005001302</PredecessorActivityUID1>
<PredecessorActivityUID2>0030</PredecessorActivityUID1>
```

into two different variables PredecessorActivityUID1,PredecessorActivityUID2

Comment: You would want to use [tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) function.

Comment: Take a few minutes to format your question. You're mixing text and code in a code markdown there it's hard to read. (And maybe you may say a word or two on what you already tried to achieve this)

Comment: Any string function which can easy do this job

Comment: @Manisha I've just mentioned one for you in my comment. You can go through the link.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with substring funtion. See if it's useful.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="PredecessorActivityUID" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="." />

  <xsl:if test="$pText">
   <PredecessorActivityUID>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, '-'), '-')" />
   </PredecessorActivityUID>

   <xsl:call-template name="split">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '-')" />
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This isn't a bad solution, but it's probably doing more work than it needs to. He just needs the string split in half, but this would be good if he had a string that had multiple `-`'s,  i.e. `123-456-789`.

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 2.0: a recursive template is not required, even if the task were to split the given string into multiple tokens.

Answer (score 1):

On this document:

```
<PredecessorActivityUID>000005001302-0030</PredecessorActivityUID>
```

Use this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/PredecessorActivityUID">
    <root>
      <xsl:variable name='uid1' select="substring-before(./text(), '-')"/>
      <xsl:variable name='uid2' select="substring-after(./text(), '-')"/>
      <PredecessorActivityUID1><xsl:value-of select='$uid1'/></PredecessorActivityUID1>
      <PredecessorActivityUID2><xsl:value-of select='$uid2'/></PredecessorActivityUID2>
    </root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

To get this result:

```
<root>
   <PredecessorActivityUID1>000005001302</PredecessorActivityUID1>
   <PredecessorActivityUID2>0030</PredecessorActivityUID2>
</root>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqn

You don't necessarily need a recursive template here, especially for such a simple requirement.  That would be good if you had to split the string into more than one piece.  `tokenize()` is great and would be supported by your processor, but your requirement is so simple that this code may be clearer (using a RegEx may be overkill for maintainability here).

This will work on XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, and shouldn't require any extensions or special processor-specific functions.  You'll get the first part of the string in the variable `$uid1` and the second part in the variable `$uid2`.  You may not need those in variables (you could just replace the `select` from the variable in the `select` of the corresponding `xsl:value-of` if you don't need to use the values more than once or for other processing directives).

Comment: "may not be supported in your processor (?)" - any conforming XSLT 2.0 processor will support `tokenize`.  A processor that claims to support XSLT 2.0 but doesn't allow `tokenize` is lying.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I'll edit.  I'm just used to working with MSXML, which only supports 1.0.  I believe there's some extension available that provides tokenize functionality for it.  At any rate, a RegEx is probably overkill for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor, I'd recommend to have a look at regular expressions which I think are one of the great advantages of 2.0 over 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="PredecessorActivityUID">
    <root>
      <PredecessorActivityUID1><xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'(^[^-]*)-(.*)','$1')"/></PredecessorActivityUID1>
      <PredecessorActivityUID2><xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'(^[^-]*)-(.*)','$2')"/></PredecessorActivityUID2>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

One does not need them here, but it's good to know them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <PredecessorActivityUID>000005001302-0030</PredecessorActivityUID>    
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PredecessorActivityUID">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(),'-')">
            <xsl:element name="PredecessorActivityUID{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <PredecessorActivityUID1>000005001302</PredecessorActivityUID1>
   <PredecessorActivityUID2>0030</PredecessorActivityUID2>
</doc>
```